# HTML - "Search by" and how to filter by selected field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

My task is to add a combo-box in the search page to allow a user to select the field she wants to search by and then search for customers using that field. In other words, there should be a “Search By” combo-box on the index page that the user selects the field to search by (Last Name, First Name, etc.) and then types in a search string and clicks a find button to perform a search and display the results on the same page. Search results should be sorted based on the field used for the search.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
<div Class="form-actions no-color"></div>
    <div class="search-item">Search</div>
    <div class="sigform_fld search-item">
        <select class="catalog">
            <option value="1">Customers</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="search-item">By</div>
    <div class="sigform_fld search-item option">
        <select class="option-1">
            <option value="2">Last Name</option>
            <option value="3">Email Address</option>
            <option value="4">Company Name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div Class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" value="@ViewData("currentFilter")" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            | @Html.ActionLink("All Customers", "Index")
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

This only filters by Last Name. How can I have one search bar that filters by the selected option (Last Name, Company Name or Email address).

Help!

Comment: Why are you splitting this into 2 separate forms?  Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: You need one form containing the `<select>` and `<input>` and your `<select>` needs a `name` attribute (say `name="SearchBy"`) and the input needs (say) `name="SearchText" but you should be doing this by strongly binding to a view model